# How to correct the parsing error in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and also programming, I would like to know why am I seeing the parsing error while my code is quite simple and easy. How can I resolve this and if yes why am I seeing this? because I use other editors (online)it shows me the correct expected result but on my local, it shows an error.

[image]

Comment: No "other online editor" would accept that as proper JavaScript, since it's not proper JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the variable each side of the condition, for example:

```
else if (currentTime >= 1 && < 12)
```

should become:

```
else if (currentTime >= 1 && currentTime < 12)
```

Hope it helps you, good luck for your learning!

Comment: Hi @asa 

Thanks a million, it really help was simple but hard to find.